# pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetPixel', 'No error message is available')

Tags: python, pywin32

Im trying to recreate the [RotBlt](https://www.codeguru.com/multimedia/a-bitblt-like-function-with-rotation-angle-rotblt/) function in python,
And then i get this error calling the fucntion on the class, and it says:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MY\Desktop\bckup\Folder rafi\New folder\python-recorder\rotblt.py", line 50, in <module>
    RotBlt(hdc, 0, 0, x, y, hdc, 0,0, 10, SRCCOPY)
  File "C:\Users\MY\Desktop\bckup\Folder rafi\New folder\python-recorder\rotblt.py", line 37, in RotBlt
    SetPixel(memDC, nX+nC, nY+nC, c)
pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetPixel', 'No error message is available')
```

The problem was the code tries to call the SetPixel fucntion but instead giving an unknown message.

Can someone tell what's wrong with these codes?

```py
from win32api import *
from win32gui import *
from win32con import *
from math import *

def RotBlt(destDC, sx1, sy1, sx2, sy2, srcDC, dx1, dy1, deg, mode):
    theta = deg * 0.01745
    # convert to radians

    # define size
    w = sx2-sx1
    h = sy2-sy1


    # define center
    cX = int(float(sx2+sx1)/2)
    cY = int(float(sy2+sy1)/2)

    #make 1:1 ratio.
    if w>h: h=w; 
    else: w=h

    # Allocate stuff
    memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(destDC)
    membmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(destDC, w, h)
    obmp = SelectObject(memDC, membmp)

    # pivot for memDC
    nC = int(float(sx1)/2)

    #rotate code (kinda slow)
    for x in range(sx1, sx2):
        for y in range(sy1, sy2):
            c = GetPixel(srcDC, x, y)
            nX = int((x-cX)*sin(theta)+(y-cY)*cos(theta))
            nY = int((x-cX)*cos(theta)-(y-cY)*sin(theta))
            SetPixel(memDC, nX+nC, nY+nC, c)

    # splash rotated image
    BitBlt(destDC, dx1, dy1, w, h, memDC, 0,0, mode)

    SelectObject(memDC, obmp)
    DeleteDC(memDC)
    DeleteObject(ombp)

while True:
    x, y = GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1)
    hwnd = GetDesktopWindow()
    hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    RotBlt(hdc, 0, 0, x, y, hdc, 0,0, 10, SRCCOPY)
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc)
    Sleep(10)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the input to your function?  As I'm unable to understand what hdc and SRCCOPY are!

Comment: the hdc is from the desktop handle to display the result in the screen, ``SRCCOPY`` is from  win32con @peerpressure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm i make the mistake, i had to change this:

```py
# pivot for memDC
nC = int(float(sx1)/2)
```

to this:

```py
# pivot for memDC
nC = int(float(w)/2)
```